# Sorting an array using reverse

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, contest-math, computer-science

I ran into an Olympiad question recently, and one challenging question surprised me:

We have an array $A$ with $n$ elements. $\operatorname{Rev}(i, j)$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq n$ reverses subarray $A[i\ldots j]$, i.e., swaps $A[j-k]$ and $A[i+k]$ for all $0 \leq k \leq j-i$.

> How many times must we use $\operatorname{Rev}(i, j)$ to sort $A$?
>
> Answer is: $\operatorname O(n)$!

How can I sort $A$, using $\operatorname{Rev}(i, j)$ $\operatorname O(n)$ times?

Comment: I think "at least" doesn't belong here, especially since $\operatorname O(n)$ is an *upper* bound.  Do you really mean:  we can use operators of the form $\operatorname{Rev}(i, j)$ at *most* $\operatorname O(n)$ times to sort $A$?

Comment: I think also the parameters of the question need to be more clearly stated.  Obviously the specific $\operatorname{Rev}$'s used need to depend on $A$, but how are we allowed to implement that dependence?  Here's an algorithm that only uses $n$ $\operatorname{Rev}$'s: `sortfrom(i, A):  { if (i < n) { m = A[i]; mi = i; for j in (i..n) { if ( A[j] <= m ) { mi = j; m = A[mi] } } Rev(i, mi, A); sortfrom(i + 1, A) } return A; }`

Comment: @LSpice sure. would you please make correction for me?

Comment: Would you please post it as an answer to discuss? @LSpice

Comment: I have proposed an edit (which seems to have been accepted) and posted my [coment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/one-nice-question-on-reverse-of-array-and-sort/3979112#comment8209823_3979069) as an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3979112) (although it almost certainly is not in the right spirit).

Comment: The obvious way would be: find the $i$th smallest element, use $\text{Rev}(i,k)$ to put that in place, $i$ running from $1$ to $n{-}1$ (the last & greatest element thus already being at the end). And $n{-}1$ is of course in $O(n)$.

Comment: really nice answer @Joffan would you please post it ?

Comment: @Joffan's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse#comment8209991_3979069) describes the algorithm in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse#comment8209823_3979069) and [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3979112).

Comment: there is one problem here @Joffan you shout iterate around array to find ith smallest element? it's take more time?

Comment: Your [point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse/3979112#comment8210053_3979069) is exactly what I meant when I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse/3979112#comment8209823_3979069) for a clearer statement of the parameters.  The question as asked only bounds the number of uses of $\operatorname{Rev}$, with no mention of which auxiliary operations we are allowed to perform, or how long they may take (and *some* auxiliary operations are necessary).

Comment: @LSpice sorry I didn't see your comments, so there is more creative proof you means every iteration we find smallest i'th element and do Rev() after it i'th smallest element is going to right place. then we should need n-1 of them?

Comment: [Yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse#comment8210089_3979069), that's exactly the algorithm I meant (although I'm not sure what you meant by "more creative proof", since it is in some sense the obvious algorithm to use $\operatorname{Rev}$ sparingly, which both @Joffan ([comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse#comment8209991_3979069)) and I ([comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse#comment8209823_3979069)) already proposed).

Comment: @Joffan I think there is a typo, after each REV(i, K) smallest eelement goes to right place !

Comment: Going to the right place is a good thing, no? And "$i$th-smallest element" was the item sought, not "smallest element". Which in this case would be "smallest element in the remaining unsorted array after the $i{-}1$ already correctly positioned at the start".

Comment: would you please add an small example? short array example and one step of rev(i, k)? thanks @Joffan

Comment: exactly as I mentioned. ith smallest element goes to right place after rev(i, k) @Joffan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it seems clear to me that this is not an answer in the spirit in which the question was meant, I post it by [request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/one-nice-question-on-reverse-of-array-and-sort#comment8209830_3979069):

I think the parameters of the question need to be more clearly stated. Obviously the specific $\operatorname{Rev}$'s used need to depend on $A$, but how are we allowed to implement that dependence? Here's an algorithm that only uses $n - 1$ $\operatorname{Rev}$'s:

```
def sortfrom(i, A):
{
    if (i < n) {
        m = A[i];
        mi = i;
        for j in (i..n) {
            if ( A[j] <= m ) {
                mi = j;
                m = A[mi]
            }
        }
        Rev(i, mi, A);
        sortfrom(i + 1, A)
    }
    return A;
}
sortfrom(1, A)
```

I used to use [repl.it](https://repl.it/) as my go-to one-shot compiler, but now it appears that you can't run code there without logging in.  Here is the above pseudoccode translated to Perl (with [your array](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse#comment8210103_3979112) hardcoded), which you can run on [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/ZZENiTwN1):

```
use v5.10;

sub sortfrom {
    my ($i, @a) = @_;
    my $n = $#a;
    if ($i < $n) {
        my $m = $a[$i];
        my $mi = $i;
        for my $j ( $i .. $n ) {
            if ( $a[$j] < $m ) {
                $m = $a[$j];
                $mi = $j;
            }
        }
        @a[$i .. $mi] = reverse @a[$i .. $mi];
        say "(", (join ", ", @a), ")";
        sortfrom($i + 1, @a);
    }
    return @a;
}

sortfrom(0, (5, 9, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6));
```

---

---

*Edit from  @Joffan* as a way of posting [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse#comment8209991_3979069) as requested, since I don't feel this merits a separate answer, being effectively a description of the code posed by [LSpice](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/87579/lspice) above:

> One obvious way to guarantee a maximum of $(n{-}1)$ uses of a $\text{Rev}$ function would be: find the $i$th smallest element at location $k$, use $\text{Rev}(i,k)$ to put that in place, with $i$ running from $1$ to $n{−}1$ (after which the last & greatest element must already be at the end). And $n{−}1$ is of course in $O(n)$.

From another comment, illustrating one step in the process:

> Suppose we are at step $i=4$, and the array looks like this $$(\color{blue}{3,5,6},20, 15, 11, 18, \color{red}7, 10)$$ where the first three steps have put the 3 smallest elements at the start. The $4$th smallest element is $7$ (as shown in red) and is found at position $8$ so we undertake $\text{Rev}(4,8)$ which produces  $$(\color{blue}{3,5,6},\color{red}7, \color{green}{18, 11, 15, 20}, 10)$$

Comment: we should find a way that we can sure that there is no more that $O(n)$ call of $rev$ is need

Comment: This algorithm uses exactly $n - 1$ calls to $\operatorname{Rev}$.

Comment: is there any math logic here that without using code we can solve it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  An algorithm has to be expressed *somehow*.  Perhaps you could point to the Olympiad question, which might give more details about acceptable versus unacceptable solutions.

Comment: the last question is ambiguity on A[j−k] and A[i+k]. for example 5, 9, 0, 2 1, 3, 4, 6. is it possible take one step of rev?

Comment: No; sorting [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse/3979112#comment8210103_3979112) array needs to put 0 at the beginning and 9 at the end, and the only single $\operatorname{Rev}$ that affects both the beginning and the end is $\operatorname{Rev}(1, 8)$ (assuming that "2 1" was meant to be "2, 1"), which doesn't sort it.

Comment: No No, I means consider at step 1 we want to use rev, what is the result after one use of rev.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't understand your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse/3979112#comment8210112_3979112).  It depends on which $\operatorname{Rev}$ you use.  If you mean what happens after the first use of $\operatorname{Rev}$ in the algorithm above, then the operation is $\operatorname{Rev}(1, 3)$, resulting is 0, 9, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6.

Comment: so nice, now I get it, and last point is that we tell above that we use rev on smallest element but here it takes two argument how set this two argument?

Comment: The (pseudo)code is there, so I'm not sure how else to answer.  $\operatorname{Rev}(1, 3)$ yields 0, 9, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6; $\operatorname{Rev}(2, 5)$ yields 0, 1, 2, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6; $\operatorname{Rev}(3, 3)$ does nothing; $\operatorname{Rev}(4, 6)$ yields 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 4, 6; $\operatorname{Rev}(5, 7)$ yields 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 6; $\operatorname{Rev}(6, 6)$ does nothing; $\operatorname{Rev}(7, 8)$ yields 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9.

Comment: is it possible make your code online and add a print for each step after REV  ?

Comment: I have done [so](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979069/sorting-an-array-using-reverse/3979112#comment8210164_3979112).